# How to create and apply properly .patch file to a single .cpp file using diff?

Tags: git, diff, patch, line-endings

I'm trying to apply a **.patch** file to a single **.cpp** file using **git diff**.

These are my files: **old.cpp** , **new.cpp** and **fix.patch**.

**old.cpp** is the original unmodified source code, **new.cpp** is the modified source and **fix.patch** is the patch I want to create which when applied to **old.cpp** should apply the changes from **new.cpp** to it. Both **old.cpp** and **new.cpp** are with **Windows (CR LF)** line endings, both files are **918 KB** large, only one line is being modified in the source.

I create the patch by putting the two files **old.cpp** and **new.cpp** in the same folder and using **Git Bash** prompt with the command:

```
git diff -u old.cpp new.cpp > fix.patch
```

The **fix.patch** file successfully appears but when I actually test it and apply it to **old.cpp** with **Git Bash** by typing:

```
patch old.cpp fix.patch
```

the patch is being applied successfully but the size of **old.cpp** *reduces* from **918 KB** to **894 KB**. After some research with **kdiff3** I found that my newly created **fix.patch** file is with **Unix (LF)** line endings and after applying it to **old.cpp**, the patched **old.cpp** is adopting **Unix (LF)** line endings too. I guess this is the reason why the file size of **old.cpp** reduces too.

My question is what **command** should I use in **git** or what else I have to do so my newly created **fix.patch** file remains with **Windows (CR LF)** line endings and after applying the patch to **old.cpp** the newly patched **old.cpp** file is with **Windows (CR LF)** line endings too and the file size does not reduce so drastically. I received a suggestion here to use `git apply` instead of `patch` but I don't know what exactly to type after `git apply` so it works *the way I want for my situation*. :(

I am using **Windows XP SP2**, **Git 1.7.6**, **Git Extensions 2.24** and **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010**.

Comment: A side question: why do you have source files that are nearly 1MB in size?

Comment: The source is not written by me. Also how is this relative to my question?

Comment: I tried manually changing the line endings of fix.patch form Unix to Windows before applying but even so after applying it the patched file is in Unix style line endings. Please help.

Comment: It's not.  That's why I posted it as a comment, and prefixed it with "side question"!

Comment: The bit of information that's always really important with line-endings questions is: what is core.autocrlf set to? (You can see with `git config core.autocrlf`.)  The other thing that isn't clear to me from your question is how exactly are you applying the patch?  Is it with `patch` in a CygWin prompt, `patch` in the "Git Bash" prompt, `git apply`, etc.?

Comment: It's the source file with the player handled actions in a popular MMORPG game.

Comment: I just checked `git config core.autocrlf`, it returned to me `true`. I am using `patch` in the "Git Bash" prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I finally solved the issue and learned my lesson aswell. :)

The patch are created with **Git Bash** command prompt:

```
git diff -u old.cpp new.cpp > fix.patch
```

Then make sure the **old.cpp** and **fix.patch** are in the **same folder** the header of **fix.patch** reads:

```
diff --git a/old.cpp b/old.cpp
index 04784e1..da68766 100644
--- a/old.cpp
+++ b/oldcpp
```

After that type in **Git Bash** prompt:

```
git apply fix.patch
```

And voila! No line messups, errors or problems. I hope this helps someone who stumbles open the same thing some day Thanks to everyone for the fast and deep replies, they helped me learn something new today. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the patch using 'git apply' instead of 'patch'. git apply will call patch but should obey any other git directives which might sort your crlf issue here. It also accepts patch options (like 'git apply -p1' for pruning path elements). I quite often also use 'git apply' to apply patches from git to CVS trees. 'git apply' doesn't require that the target be a git repository.

Comment: I'm sorry patthoyts, but I'm really unexperienced with `git apply`. Would you mind pointing me out how exactly should I apply my patch the way I want using `git apply`. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Just like you would use 'patch'. The patch file contains information about the file to be modified in the patch header so 'git apply -p0 changes.patch' will apply the patch to the current directory.

Comment: Oh, now I got error - `fix.patch:8 trailing whitespace` and `error: patch failed: old.cpp:1419` and `error: old.cpp: patch does not apply`

Comment: Give us a clue: "Nevermind I fixed it." - It would be useful to know so that I/others avoid the same issues..

Comment: @Philip Oakley, I couldn't post the answer at the time, because the website required me to wait 8 hours before replying to myself. I just posted my solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `--include` flag.

```
git apply patch.patch --include=new.cpp
```